# Restrict Date to choose from datepicker in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to provide user to choose only list of date i have specified in datepicker. For Example :

If i specify date like below:-

either

1). june 1 to june 7

or

2). 4th July, 10th July, 29th August (in any format like 04/07, 10/07, 29/08)

Than in datepicker, it should have only those dates which user can select, rest of the date should be disabled.

Here is demo, what I am looking for :- http://www.islandroutes.com/shore-excursions/#port-date-sel

If you select any cruise line, and than any ship name, and than there is option of select date. All dates are not clickable, Only certain dates are clickable.

I want to have same functionality in my website.

I could not understand code there, Can anyone help me learning that.

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I have already gone through all datepicker jquery ui, but none of them provide modification i need. I think i will need something custom.

I have already gone through :- http:// api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and http:// jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: You can find useful help here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var availableDates = [9,14,15]; //desired Days

function available(date) {

   dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

   if ($.inArray(date.getDate(), availableDates) != -1) {
      return [true, "","Available"];
   } else {
     return [false,"","unAvailable"];
   }
 }

 $('#date').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: available });
```

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what i am looking for ? But, Can i have month and year option too, like in `availableDates = [ dd/mm/yyyy, dd/mm/yyyy]`

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Bingo, This is Done! Thank you so much :)